# DataTables Django Rest Framework JSON

Tags: json, datatables, django-rest-framework

I'm not able to display the json payload from `Django Rest Framework` in a `DataTable` and I'm not sure why. I've overwritten the serializer to better format the json payload however it still isn't working.

I can verify that the JSON request is firing and getting the proper information back (can see in the console of the browser) however the table says `"No data to display"`

Here is my json payload:

```
{"data":[
    {"product_name":"123",
     "mdr_class":1,
     "category":1,
     "eo_role":1,
     "division":1,
     "created_by":"root"}
    {"product_name":"1234",
     "mdr_class":1,
     "category":1,
     "eo_role":1,
     "division":1,
     "created_by":"root"}
     ...
    ]}
```

singleline of `JSON`:

```
{"data":[{"product_name":"123","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"},{"product_name":"1234","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"},{"product_name":"234234","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"},{"product_name":"432","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"},{"product_name":"432134","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"},{"product_name":"432134","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"},{"product_name":"432134","mdr_class":1,"category":1,"eo_role":1,"division":1,"created_by":"root"}]}
```

and my HTML file with the AJAX call outlined.

```
<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>MDR Class</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>EO Role</th>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
    </tr>
<thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>MDR Class</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>EO Role</th>
        <th>Division</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
    </tr>
<tfoot>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {

        ajax: {
        "processing":true,
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/entry/?format=json',
        "dataSrc":"",
        },


        columns: [
            {"mData":"product_name"},
            {"mData":"mdr_class"},
            {"mData":"category"},
            {"mData":"eo_role"},
            {"mData":"division"},
            {"mData":"created_by"},
            ]
        } );


});

</script>
```

Again - I can see the json in the console, but the data doesn't display. 
Do I need to modify how the json is being presented to the DataTable? I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.
The script was incorrectly formatted.
Here is the working script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {

        ajax: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/entry/?format=json',
        },


        columns: [
            {data:"product_name"},
            {data:"mdr_class"},
            {data:"category"},
            {data:"eo_role"},
            {data:"division"},
            {data:"created_by"},
            ]
        } );


});
```